# Notification is not get triggered For iHealth BG5 (BG5ConnectNot,BG5DisConnectNoti)

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, health-monitoring, ios-bluetooth

we are developing a health care iOS application. We are dealing with BLE and non-BLE Bluetooth devices. Similarly, we reading Blood glucose (BG) using iHealth BG device model BG5, it is a non-BLE Bluetooth device.

The iHealth dev team Developed an SDK to read measurements from their devices. A copy of the same they shared with us. So we are using this SDK to fetch the data from the devices. As previously mentioned BG5 device is used to measure the blood glucose. The SDK implemented like the device communication begins from the device did connect notification.

We registered for the same on view did appear method, it got reflected in the NSNoticationCenter object too.

Like this 
BG5DisConnectNoti, 0x1b19d6ff0, 0x10100be70, 1400
BG5ConnectNoti, 0x1b19d6ff0, 0x10100be70, 1400

and registered like this

define BG5ConnectNoti @"BG5ConnectNoti"
define BG5DisConnectNoti @"BG5DisConnectNoti"

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceDidConnect:) name:BG5ConnectNoti object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceDidDisconnect:) name:BG5DisConnectNoti object:nil];

I think notification is broadcasted by the SDK. How can we debug to find that SDK is broadcasting it or not?

Any solution to get trigger the did device connected method?

Plese, help to resolve this issue.
Thanks for the support in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding an entry on the info Plist for receiving the notification from the BG5 device.

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
<array>
    <string>com.jiuan.BGV31</string>
</array>
```

"com.jiuan.BGV31"
This is an External accessory protocols id that iHealth registered with apple.

I got this from demo project they shared with the SDK.

Regards
Joseph